# 3d printing Communism

Tags: planets

Imagine this,

1. Printing advances til everyone has one. 2030-50 timeframe
2. There is a public utility
3. Electricity credits are issued equally to everyone to run their printer
4. Then people can make whatever they want and will have equal access to energy
5. All energy resources will also be Nationalized and supplied to the utility
6. The utility will fund itself by collecting credits to run its own printer and give the profit back to the credit pool. Some small inequality since utility workers are paid in credits.
7. There is the possibility energy will be under utilized. So maybe people are only guaranteed x credits but can keep consuming if there is slack.

Do you think this would work?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, 69758. At present your question lacks some detail; I'm assuming that by 3D printer, you're describing something more akin to a Star Trek Replicator, and the environment you describe also sounds rather Trekkian. Is that what you mean, and if so, how do does your system get people to contribute, rather than merely consume? For instance, if everyone gets an equal share, what's forcing anyone to be the person who goes to work at the power grid?

Comment: That is a good question but the labor will be minimal and the grid will be near automated.

Comment: @TimBII I assume he meant a normal printer... Not everyone has a good printer at home. User69758 please add more details. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: I mean a 3d printer with 2030 or so capability

Comment: Is it possible for you to define what 2030 capability is? Does that mean plastic only? Or metal powder? Or resin printing? What size scale are we talking about (average print is like 30cmX30cm) and how fast does a print take (because right now, its like 15 minutes for a plastic coin). Or do you mean something like the Star Trek Replicator which can recreate anything from scratch with no materials?

Comment: The current million dollar commercial printers are Star Trek replicators, price is falling about 30% yearly.

Comment: I would advice a crash course on worldbuilding, by taking the [tour] and visiting the [help].

Comment: Sounds like you are basically recreating Star Trek society in that sense. If anyone can make anything, material value goes out the window. The could technically print their own generator and their own fuel to power their replicator. If its easily accessibly, you essentially have the key to transcend the material needs of society. So there would be no need for communism.

Comment: A million dollar commercial printer might be able to print fancy metal objects, but its not going to print me a pot brownie. The Replicators can duplicate almost all matter. There is a huge difference between a muti-material printer. And a "print everything" printer (especially if its only a couple minutes, compared to the hours and days you need for commercial printers).

Comment: You would print an ore processor, mine dirt then proceed to make things. 3d printed organic material exists.

Comment: Define "equal access". Does everyone get 100 units of electricity a month and that's it, or everyone can draw as much power as they want, whether it's the fellow who runs his printer one hour a week or the workaholic who runs his printer 24/7 minus reloading time? If the latter, how much excess capacity can the utility bring online at short notice?

Comment: I was thinking 100 credits, and there is the expectation of under utilization. Or else a certain amount is guaranteed, and the rest is sort of discretionary. Good question

Comment: There are not that many things to print in 2050 for most people that would really make things better. Please consider that you would be investing time into finding whatever you want to print. I don't know where you want to go with this, but that's not enough to base your world upon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given unrealistic premises, any consequence can be possible.

To begin with, you cannot 3D print energy and raw materials. Those have to come from somewhere. And for them to come you need to supply something in exchange. That something is usually money.

You cannot 3D print money, for the same reason any half decent central bank doesn't want to print money just for the sake of it: inflation.

> Over time, hyperinflation in Zimbabwe reduced the Zimbabwe dollar to one of the lowest valued currency units in the world. It was redenominated three times (in 2006, 2008 and 2009), with denominations up to a 100 trillion banknote issued. The final redenomination produced the "fourth dollar" (ZWL), which was worth $10^{25}$ ZWD (first dollars). 
>   The [Zimbabwean dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwean_dollar) is a famous example of the danger of inflation

[image: 100 trillion dollar note]

Comment: The utility would be state run and print only the capital it needs

Comment: As the director I "need" an extra million dollars. Human greed and envy are not cured by technology.

Comment: Good point ....